# " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' " while installing geopy

Tags: python, django, svn, pip, geopy

I'm trying to install the packages from a requirements file for a django project.

The problem is that while installing geopy I get the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'.

I'm running within a virtualenv with python 2.7.3.

The exact command is:

```
sudo pip-python install -r requirements.pip
```

The problematic line from the requirements file is:

```
-e svn+http://geopy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk@144#egg=geopy-0.94.1_pre.dev_r144-py2.7-dev_r144
```

I have setuptools and distribute 0.6.34 (I beleive that setuptools is just an alias for distribute). setuptools_subversion is at version 3.1

I'm running Fedora 17.

The complete error is as follows:

```
Obtaining geopy from svn+http://geopy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk@144#egg=geopy-0.94.1_pre.dev_r144-py2.7-dev_r144 (from -r requirements.pip (line 50))
  Unrecognized .svn/entries format in /home/myself/leona-integration/leona/src/geopy
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 223, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 936, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.update_editable(not self.is_download)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 384, in update_editable
    vcs_backend.obtain(self.source_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 86, in obtain
    if self.check_destination(dest, url, rev_options, rev_display):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs/__init__.py", line 184, in check_destination
    if self.compare_urls(existing_url, url):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs/__init__.py", line 142, in compare_urls
    return (self.normalize_url(url1) == self.normalize_url(url2))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs/__init__.py", line 136, in normalize_url
    return urllib.unquote(url).rstrip('/')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1204, in unquote
    res = s.split('%')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

It's already been pointed out in the comments that the line "Unrecognized .svn/entries format in..." is just a warning, and not the cause of the exception.

Comment: The message is not an error but a warning, and not the cause of the AttributeError. I documented this in the [`subversion_setuptools` README](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools_subversion) (I am it's author). :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by commenting the problematic line in the requirements file and adding the following line:

```
geopy==0.94.1
```